# Obtain the SUM from a column by ID from an un-normalized table?

Tags: mysql, sum, database-normalization

I have a database from a hospital. In a table there's 1 or more transaction numbers and almost all of them only contain 1 Doctor ID. The table hasn't been normalized yet.

The data looks like the following:

```
Trans_No    |Doctor_ID  |Trans_Type                     |PM |Cost
10.853329   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.853329   |10004      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.853329   |           |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 1077   |F  |2000.00
10.836033   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.836033   |10001      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.836033   |           |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 3137   |F  |0.00
10.836032   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.836032   |10004      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.836032   |           |PEMERIKSAAN RADIOLOGI NO 0932.1|R  |15000.00
10.836034   |10604      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.836034   |           |PEMERIKSAAN RADIOLOGI NO 0932.1|R  |20000.00
```

I know my table needs to be normalized but I can't change the database since I have no right do so.

Problem is how to get result like this:

```
Doctor_ID  |medicine    |radiology
10004      |2000.00     |15000.00
10001      |0.00        |0.00
10604      |0.00        |20000.00
```

PM='F' as medicine and PM='R' as radiology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   doctor_id, SUM(medicine) medicine, SUM(radiology) radiology
FROM     (
  SELECT   MAX(doctor_id) doctor_id,
           SUM(IF(pm='F', cost, NULL)) medicine,
           SUM(IF(pm='R', cost, NULL)) radiology
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY Trans_No
) t
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a51/1/0).